# CASE WHEN Y THEN EN Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

quisiera saber por favor saber como paso este codigo en `SQL` a `HQL`, ya que no se como hibernate utiliza estas sentencias:

```
CASE WHEN  s.id IS NULL THEN s.direccion else l.direccion end as calle
```